# ng-repeat and ng-controller on the same DOM element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can we attach ng-controller and ng-repeat to the same DOM element? 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXE4c/4/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-controller="UserController" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="toggleSelectedUser()" ng-switch on="isSelectedUser()">
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true">
            <td colspan="2">
                {{user.desc}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the code:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])     
    .controller("UserController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.users = [
            {name : "Anup Vasudeva", email : "anup.vasudeva2009@gmail.com", desc : "Description about Anup Vasudeva"},
            {name : "Amit Vasudeva", email : "amit.vasudeva2009@gmail.com", desc : "Description about Amit Vasudeva"},
            {name : "Vijay Kumar", email : "vijay.kumar@gmail.com", desc : "Description about Vijay Kumar"}
        ];
        $scope.selected = false;

        $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function() {
            $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
        };

        $scope.isSelectedUser = function() {
            return $scope.selected;
        };
    }]);
```

I think it makes sense to bind `ng-controller` and `ng-repeat` to the same DOM element. The scope created by ng-repeat can be managed by the controller. What I want is the variable `selected` should be unique for each scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should break your controller into `UserListController` and `UserController`. The list of users should be part of UserListController and the each item can be managed by `UserController`

Something like

```
<table ng-controller='UserListController'>
        <tbody ng-controller="UserController" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="toggleSelectedUser()" ng-switch on="isSelectedUser()" ng-init="user=user">
```

So the user controller becomes

```
angular.module("myApp", [])     
    .controller("UserController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.selected = false;

        $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function() {
            $scope.user.selected = !$scope.selected;
        };

        $scope.isSelectedUser = function() {
            return $scope.user.selected;
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: How would this look using the "controller as" syntax?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `ng-init="user=user"`? It seems redundant, but if the ngRepeat changed to `ng-repeat="singleUser in users"` then you could change it to `ng-init="user=singleUser"` without changing the controller code. Is that the only reason?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is the variable selected should be unique for each scope.

Yes you can.

### Multiple controller way

You can create root controller `mainController` and add to your model `users` new controller per user.

After that, call new controller in ng-repeat as `ng-controller="user.ctrl"`

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/662/)**</kbd>

I would write something like:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <table>
        <tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-controller="user.ctrl" ng-click="toggleSelectedUser()" ng-switch on="isSelectedUser()">
            <tr>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-switch-when="true">
                <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px">{{user.desc}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
        ctrl: fooCtrlA,
        name: "AAAAA",
        email: "a2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about AAAA"
    }, {
        ctrl: fooCtrlB,
        name: "BBBBB",
        email: "b2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about BBBBB"
    }, {
        ctrl: fooCtrlC,
        name: "CCCCC",
        email: "c2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about CCCC"
    }];
});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];

function fooCtrlA($scope) {
    $scope.selected = true;
    $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function () {
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
    $scope.isSelectedUser = function () {
        return $scope.selected;
    };
}

function fooCtrlB($scope) {
    $scope.selected = false;
    $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function () {
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
    $scope.isSelectedUser = function () {
        return $scope.selected;
    };
}

function fooCtrlC($scope) {
    $scope.selected = false;
    $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function () {
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
    $scope.isSelectedUser = function () {
        return $scope.selected;
    };
}
```

However you can see we have **code duplicate!!**. Each "child" controller has the same logic:

```
    $scope.selected = false;
    $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function () {
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
    $scope.isSelectedUser = function () {
        return $scope.selected;
    };
```

If you want to make your code work, I would use `ng-model`.

### Other way with ng-model

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/663/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="toggleSelectedUser(user)" ng-switch on="isSelectedUser(user)">
            <tr ng-model="user">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-switch-when="true">
                <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px">{{user.desc}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**and controller with modified model:**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
        selected: false,
        name: "AAAAA",
        email: "a2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about AAAA"
    }, {
        selected: false,
        name: "BBBBB",
        email: "b2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about BBBBB"
    }, {
        selected: false,
        name: "CCCCC",
        email: "c2009@gmail.com",
        desc: "Description about CCCC"
    }];


    $scope.toggleSelectedUser = function (user) {
        user.selected = !user.selected;
    };
    $scope.isSelectedUser = function (user) {
        return user.selected;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your first solution, do you think there would be an issue if my number of users scales? In your second solution, the ng-controller and ng-repeat are in the different DOM element. Would it be possible to have both ng-controller and ng-repeat in the same DOM element?

Comment: As you see if we talk about functionality 2nd way work as well. About 1st solution, you can't put main controller to `ng-repeat`. Because `ng-repeat` DOM element represents item aka `user`, not `users`. We need someone who will manage all `users` model. So as I know - no way.