# Passing data to a template in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following structure:

```
<div id="jobs" ng-controller="JobsCtrl">
    <div class="job" ng-controller="JobCtrl" job-tpl ng-repeat="job in jobs"></div>
</div>
```

My `JobsCtrl` will handle date to create a list of items and some interaction for the entire item list, while `JobCtrl` will only handle interaction for single items.

Now how can I pass the data from `JobsCtrl` down to my `JobCtrl`?

At the moment `JobsCtrl` is just pretty basic and all it does is create some data and specify the template:

```
app.controller('JobsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.jobs = [
    {
        'html': 'testing',
        'date': '23 saf',
        'type': 'job--hiring'
    },
    {
        'html': 'test',
        'date': '23 saf',
        'type': 'job--hiring'
    },
    {
        'html': 'test',
        'date': '23 saf',
        'type': 'job--hiring'
    },
    {
        'html': 'test',
        'date': '23 saf',
        'type': 'job--hiring'
    },
    {
        'html': 'test',
        'date': '23 saf',
        'type': 'job--hiring'
    }
]
}).directive('jobTpl', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'job.html'
    }
})
```

But in my `JobCtrl` I want to modify that data and do some more stuff with it

```
app.controller('JobCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Handle data for one item here
})
```

How can I do something like this? Or am I just thinking in a wrong way?

Comment: why have to use `JobCtrl`? just `JobsCtrl` not working in your case?

Comment: @Freedom, because I want to separate interactions between my list of items and single items. And some of the interactions will alter date and change the DOM, so I thought it was a better idea to keep them separate.

Comment: I think it's more simple to keep the model in one scope. If you separate the scope, the same item will exist in two scope(`JobsCtrl`(parent scope) and `JobCtrl`(child scope)). It may bring difficulty to maintain.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508666/sharing-a-variable-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `JobCtrl`, `$scope.job` should work

Comment: Would you consider it a good idea to do it like this? I'm quite new to angular and just looking at what the best setup is.

Comment: I've never used it but it seems like it's a [great](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589086/ng-repeat-and-ng-controller-on-the-same-dom-element) [idea](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2450-Using-ngController-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS.htm).